# How to make room reflection using Cubemap

Tags: opengl, directx, shader, render

I am trying to use a cube map of the inside of a room to create some reflections on walls, ceiling and floor.
But when I use the cube map, the reflected image is not correct. The point of view seems to be false.
To be correct I use a different cube map for each walls, floor or ceiling. The cube map is calculated from the center of the plane looking at the room.
Are there specialized techniques to achieve such effect ?

Comment: could you post some code? some more examples of your work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I use the cube map, the reflected image is not correct.

Yes, this is to be expected.

> Are there specialized techniques to achieve such effect ?

Indeed there is; by which I mean years ago I came across an techdemo made by ATI in which they implemented some correction. IIRC this was part of their "Ruby" (the ATI demo, not the language) series of presentations and papers. Unfortunately I can't find it anymore.

*EDIT* At Siggraph2012 a technique called "Parallax-corrected cubemaps" was presented in a paper about realtime illumination. This looks very similar.